# How do I convert a string of a list back to a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a string which is actually a list, e.g.:

```
a = "[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]"
```

and I want to convert it back to a list.

I want my output to be like this:

```
a = [['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]
```

so it being an actual list instead of a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can parse the string using the `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> thestring = "[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]"
>>> thelist = ast.literal_eval(thestring)
>>> print(thelist)
[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]
>>> type(thelist)
<class 'list'>
>>> print(thelist[0])
['hey', '4A48']
>>> type(thelist[0])
<class 'list'>
```

and (in this simple case) go back to string via `repr`:

```
>>> repr(thelist)
"[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]"
>>> repr(thelist) == thestring
True
```

`eval` works too, but will execute any python code inside the string, which could be a security risk or may have unwanted side effects.
It's much safer to use `ast.literal_eval`, even on trusted inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `eval` for that

```
>>> a = "[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]"
>>> l=eval(a)
>>> l[0]
['hey', '4A48']
>>> type(l)
list
```

for comparison:

```
>>> timeit(ast.literal_eval(a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.6 µs per loop

>>> timeit(eval(a))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.72 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the input or can assure that nobody makes any monkey business you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list)

example (you have to pass the code as a string):

```
result = eval("[['hey', '4A48'], ['hello', '4D42']]")
```

`result` will be your list of lists.